# How to make foreach to read data from list not from the first item?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>().ToList();

foreach (Row row in rows)
{
  //some logic
}
```

In code above I get some rows collection and make List from it,
then I make foreach loop on the List.

I need to make foreach to read from the second item in the list of rows, not from the first item as it implemented.

What the elegant way to implement it?

Comment: do you want to keep the foreach? if you are willing to use a for loop, you could just initialize the iterator to 1 to skip over the first result.

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you mean here. You're iterating over all the rows at the moment, that's all. Do you mean you want to iterate over all but the first element? If so, use `Skip`...

Comment: Sounds like you dont even need the for loop if you only want the second item.   List[1] (zero based index)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`IEnumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>().ToList(); //.ToList() is not neccesarry for this example, but may be necessary later on.
foreach (Row row in rows.Skip(1))
{
    //some logic
}
```

This will start from the 2nd row.

Comment: Materialization (i.e. `ToList()`) is redundant here

Comment: @DmitryBychenko You are right, it's redundant in the loop context, however it doesn't mean that it won't be used later on in the code as an `IList`. I added a comment just to be sure, but removing it would be incorrect, as it may break OP's code.